# How do I select the category XML nodes with XPath regardless of specific Id's?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlnode

In C# I am using the following code to read in the XML file into an XmlDocument.
In doing this I am trying to select all of the "category" nodes regardless of their specific category-id's using XPath. In total I have over 200 categories so selecting them one by one is not really an option.

I've tried countless variations of "category", "/category", "//catalog/category", etc. however nodeList always returns null. I've also tried following the following website along with many others. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

[XPath Examples - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filename);

XmlNodeList nodeList;
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

nodeList = root.SelectNodes("/catalog/category")



// Sample XML Document 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.site.com/catalog/2012-10-31" catalog-id="sports">
    <header>
        <image-settings>
            <internal-location base-path="/"/>
            <view-types>
                <view-type>large</view-type>
                <view-type>small</view-type>
                <view-type>swatch</view-type>
            </view-types>
            <alt-pattern>${productname}</alt-pattern>
            <title-pattern>${productname}</title-pattern>
        </image-settings>
    </header>

    <category category-id="root">
        <display-name xml:lang="x-default">Store Catalog</display-name>
        <description xml:lang="x-default">Holds categories for Store</description>
        <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        <template/>
        <page-attributes>
            <page-title xml:lang="x-default">Store Catalog</page-title>
            <page-description xml:lang="x-default">Welcome to the Store</page-description>
        </page-attributes>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="enableCompare">false</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="showInMenu">false</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
        <refinement-definitions>
            <refinement-definition type="category" bucket-type="none">
                <display-name xml:lang="x-default">Category</display-name>
                <sort-mode>category-position</sort-mode>
                <cutoff-threshold>5</cutoff-threshold>
            </refinement-definition>
        </refinement-definitions>
    </category>

    <category category-id="whats-new">
        <display-name xml:lang="x-default">NEW</display-name>
        <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        <parent>root</parent>
        <position>25.0</position>
        <template>rendering/category/categoryproducthits</template>
        <page-attributes>
            <page-title xml:lang="x-default">What's New - New at Store</page-title>
            <page-description xml:lang="x-default">Learn what's new at the store.</page-description>
        </page-attributes>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="contentOnly">false</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="displaySubNav">false</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="dropdownNavSlot1">dropdown-left7</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="enableCompare">false</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="enableslotat3">true</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="enableslotat4">true</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="enableslotat9">true</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="showInMenu">true</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="showShadeSelector">false</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="showSubCollectionsAsTabs">false</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </category>

// cut for brevity - the above category nodes are the same format as the rest of the XML document.
```

Comment: Namespaces. Note that while *in a document*, you can say up front `xmlns="..."` to mean that all unadorned names are in that namespace, **you cannot do that in an xpath** - in an xpath, which conceptually stands *apart* from any document, you have to say exactly which namespaces names are in, usually using an `XmlNamespaceManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your XML uses an explicit namespace, it seems you have to specify it in your SelectNodes method:

```
 XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
 nsmgr.AddNamespace("cc", "http://www.site.com/catalog/2012-10-31");
 XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("/cc:catalog/cc:category", nsmgr);
```